# ConTeXt XML: Nested section elements

Tags: sectioning, context, xml

I am trying to produce PDF from XML with ConTeXt. Currently, I am struggling with this: The XML file is in JATS, and JATS usually does not specify the levels of sections. There is an optional attribute `disp-level` that I have used until now, but it turns out that this attribute is often ommitted. This means I have to guess at which section level we are at. In order to do I have tried checking how far we are away from `<body>`: If `<body>` is the parent of the current element the current element's level is `section`, if it is the parent of the parent of the current element the current element's level is `subsection`, and so on.

```
\startbuffer[test]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD v1.0 20120330//EN"
                  "JATS-journalpublishing1.dtd">
<article xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" dtd-version="1.0" article-type="other">
<front>
</front>
<body>
<sec id="section-heading">
  <title>Section Heading</title>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <sec id="subsection-heading">
    <title>Subsection Heading</title>
    <p>More Text</p>
  </sec>
</sec>
</body>
<back>
</back>
</article>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:jatssetups
    \xmlsetsetup{#1}{*}{-}
    \xmlsetsetup{#1}{article|body|sec|p}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:jatssetups}

\startxmlsetups xml:article
    \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body
    \startdocument
    \xmlflush{#1}
    \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:p
    \xmlflush{#1}\par
\stopxmlsetups

% Sections

\startxmlsetups xml:sec
    \xmlfilter{#1}{../../body/command(xml:sec:section)} 
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:sec:section
    \startsection[title=\xmlfirst{#1}{/title}]
      \xmlall{#1}{/!title}
    \stopsection
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:sec:subsection
    \startsubsection[title=\xmlfirst{#1}{/title}]
      \xmlall{#1}{/!title}
    \stopsubsection
\stopxmlsetups


\xmlprocessbuffer{main}{test}{}
```

However, this produces an fatal error ("TeX capacity exceeded."). Perhaps someone has a better idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to map the `<section>` tags to `\startsectionlevel` macros, which can be nested:

```
\starttext
\startstructurelevel[title=Section heading]
  Some text
  \startstructurelevel[title=Subsection heading]
    More text
  \stopstructurelevel
\stopstructurelevel
\stoptext
```

The default mapping is that the first level maps to a chapter, the second level maps to a section, and so on. You can change this setting using:

```
\definesectionlevels
  [default]
  [
    section,
    subsection,
    subsubsection,
    subsubsubsection,
  ]
```

With the above setup, the first level `\startstructurelevel` is mapped to `\startsection`, the second level `\startstructurelevel` is mapped to `\startsubsection` and so on until four nested levels.

You can change the style of the document using normal setup commands that change the style of `\startsection` etc. Here is an example:

```
\definesectionlevels
  [default]
  [
    section,
    subsection,
    subsubsection,
    subsubsubsection,
  ] 

\setuphead[section][color=blue]
\setuphead[subsection][color=red]

\starttext
\startstructurelevel[title=Section heading]
  Some text
  \startstructurelevel[title=Subsection heading]
    More text
  \stopstructurelevel
\stopstructurelevel
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on Aditya's input I can now come up with this solution:

```
\startbuffer[test]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD v1.0 20120330//EN"
                  "JATS-journalpublishing1.dtd">
<article xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" dtd-version="1.0" article-type="other">
<front>
</front>
<body>
<sec id="section-heading">
  <title>Section Heading</title>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <sec id="subsection-heading">
    <title>Subsection Heading</title>
    <p>More Text</p>
  </sec>
</sec>
</body>
<back>
</back>
</article>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:jatssetups
    \xmlsetsetup{#1}{*}{-}
    \xmlsetsetup{#1}{article|body|sec|p}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:jatssetups}

\startxmlsetups xml:article
    \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body
    \startdocument
    \xmlflush{#1}
    \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:p
    \xmlflush{#1}\par
\stopxmlsetups

% Sections

\startxmlsetups xml:sec
    \startstructurelevel [title=\xmlfilter{#1}{/title/command(xml:sec:title)}]
     \xmlflush{#1}
    \stopstructurelevel
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:sec:title
    \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\definestructurelevels [default] [section,subsection,subsubsection]
\setuphead [section] [style=\bf]
\setuphead [subsection] [style=\em]


\xmlprocessbuffer{main}{test}{}
```